# Как выполнить скрипт PHP с пустыми переменными?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, pdo

у меня есть форма для изменения Имени, Фамилии, Логина и тд. Как можно выполнить запрос, если пользователь хочет изменить только имя, чтобы остальные поля в БД не были затронуты?

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
$company_link = $_POST['company_link'];
$company_desc = $_POST['company_desc'];
$pictmp = $_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'];
$picname = $_FILES['icon']['name'];
$path = "../img/avatars/";
$picdir = $path.$picname;


$sql = 'UPDATE `users` SET `name` = :name, `surname` = :surname,`login` = :login,`icon` = :icon WHERE `users`.`id` = :user_id ';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(":user_id",$_SESSION['user']['id'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(":name",$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(":surname",$surname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(":login",$login,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(":icon",$picname,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
move_uploaded_file($pictmp,$picdir);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: $sql = 'UPDATE `users` SET `name` = :name WHERE `users`.`id` = :user_id ';

Answer (score 0):

Если подумать пару секунд… до на ум приходит два варианта решения данной задачи

1. Как обычно это реализовано на сайтах, при загрузки страницы если у пользователя эти поля уже заполнены и они должны отображаться на сайте, то в них указываются значения из бд, тем самым при отправки формы значения будут перезаписаны теми же самыми значениями, а если использовать какие-то фреймворк по типу ларавель так и вовсе будут перезаписаны только те значения которые  изменил пользователь, потому как Eloquent сравнивает старые значения и новые.
2. Написать что-то похожее на систему из выше описанной которую использует ларавель только самому, обновлять только те поля которые были изменены пользователем.